# Linux Ubuntu 16.04 Blank Screen

Tags: 16.04, gdisk

I have a DELL Inspiran laptop. Recently I had a problem my External Hard Disk is not detected.

So I followed the below steps,

> sudo mount /dev/sdxn /mnt

I got a message "GPT table corrupted" so I followed this solution
[Fixing corrupt backup GPT table?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/386752/fixing-corrupt-backup-gpt-table)

> sudo gdisk /dev/sda
>
> w

After re-starting the laptop I can't able to see the OS only blank screen is displaying.

Only I can see F2 and F12 key options

Help me how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 4):

`/dev/sda` is very likely your local Hard Drive, not the external. So you might have destroyed the partition table on your computer.

You should boot with a Linux Live USB and run [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) to recover the partition(s) on /dev/sda.

> TestDisk is powerful free data recovery software! It was primarily
>   designed to help recover lost partitions

Next time, you should first find out the proper name of your hard drive using `lsblk` or use a graphical tool that can fix Partition tables (e.g. [gparted](http://gparted.org/))

Comment: Thank you very much i don't know what to do.. i'll try this