# Cannot connect HDD with GPT (unrecognised disk label)

Tags: partitioning, mount

I have a 1TB internal HDD, that I'm trying to connect externally via SATA/IDE adapter and recover its data. When I connect the drive, it won't show up among other drives.

In GParted (GUI) I see:

- partition - unallocated
- file system - unallocated
- warning - unrecognised disk label

Output of `sudo fsdisk -l`:

> GPT PMBR size mismatch (1953525167 != 244190645) will be corrected by
>   w(rite). 
>   Disk /dev/sdc: 931,5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 244190646
>   sectors Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes Sector size
>   (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes I/O size
>   (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes Disklabel type: dos Disk
>   identifier: 0x9a95f0ae
>
> Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type /dev/sdc1
>   1 1953525167 1953525167  7,3T ee GPT

When I attemped data rescue in GParted, I've got:

> The disk scan by gpart did not find any recognizable file systems on this disk.

When trying to mount the drive directly, I get:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sdc /media/sebastian/mountpoint
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc, missing codepage or helper program, or other error
```

Is there any way I could recover data?

Comment: Try testdisk for data recovery!

Comment: What does gdisk show? Do not write any data if MBR or post output above so it can be reviewed. https://askubuntu.com/questions/386752/fixing-corrupt-backup-gpt-table/386802#386802 & http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html

Comment: @George It worked, you saved my day, Sir! Thank you. If you would add a solution, I would confirm it.

Oldfred, Thank you for more information provided.