# Could use your help recovering HFS+ external HDD that won't mount and has corrupted GPT table

Tags: mount, data-recovery

I'm attempting to mount an Apple HFS/HFS+ formatted external HDD on my Ubuntu 18. box.The reason I'm attempting this is that my Mac wants to try to initialize the drive as though its blank. Attempts at using DiskUtility failed (cannot repair or verify). I am now running into a host of issues try to mount under linux. What I've tried:

```
sudo apt-get install hfsprogs -y
sudo mkdir /media/exthdd
sudo mount -t hfsplus -o force,rw /dev/sdb2 /media/exthdd
```

The above resulted in an error when trying to mount:

```
mount: /mnt: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

When I attempted this:

```
sudo fsck.hfsplus /dev/sdb
```

I got that following:

```
Can't stat /dev/sdb1
Can't stat /dev/sdb1: No such file or directory
```

Here is the error and info I found using fdisk

```
 sudo fdisk -l
GPT PMBR size mismatch (4294967294 != 7814037164) will be corrected by w(rite).
The primary GPT table is corrupt, but the backup appears OK, so that will be used.
Disk /dev/sdb: 3.7 TiB, 4000787028480 bytes, 7814037165 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 0CC734C1-E271-4E6B-9B75-A18C548BCDB5

Device      Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1      40     409639     409600  200M EFI System
/dev/sdb2  409640 7813774983 7813365344  3.7T Apple HFS/HFS+
```

I could really use someone's help as I very much want to recover the data. I don't know what else to try. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fixing corrupt backup GPT table?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/386752/fixing-corrupt-backup-gpt-table)

Comment: Hi Emmet, thanks for your reply. I have read over the link you submitted. Frankly, I'm at a loss as to whether or not my external, non system disk, falls under the context of the thread or not. As this is sensitive, I'm hoping someone can further clarify whether or not it does. I'll standby in the meantime. Again, thanks for providing the link.