# failure reading sector sector 0x465aa00 from hd0

Tags: kernel

Currently in grub2 ( trying to solve a boot problem )  , coming from this post
https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/418401
However whenever I am tying to set the Linux kernel using this command
`linux (hd0,gpt1)/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0.-37-generic`

I am getting

`error: failure reading sector 0x465aa00 from 'hd0'`

It cannot be a hard drive problem because i can clearly use `ls -la (hd0,gpt1)/` or any such `ls` commands and can see the contents ( i wouldn't have known which vmlinuz to take without seeing the contents of boot )

So if anyone can help me on this it would be really appreciated .
Also there are no gdisk or fdisk commands so most of the other posts here are kind of not useful.
Here is a picture: https://ibb.co/743rj68

Comment: Is your sytem a dual boot?

Comment: Tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1143319/ubuntu-fails-to-boot-failure-reading-sector)?

Comment: How do you know it cannot be a hard drive problem?  Your logic is faulty as most drives contains many sectors and the contents of a file aren't located in the partition table, or directory used in your provided logic.  Have you checked your drive health?  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools  If you've done checks, you've provided no evidence of any  (eg. no mention of running of `badblocks`, SMART checks etc)

Comment: @AkshatZala no it is not dual boot

Comment: @guiverc  Indeed I haven't done it , I'll check it and update accordingly .

Comment: @kashish that doesn't give me a problem , it prints the folders perfectly

Comment: Can you please boot from live cd  and please try bootrepair

Comment: @AkshatZala  yes i am goign to try smartmontools and bootrepair

Comment: @guiverc here is the SMART data page https://ibb.co/zZYgs7y also this is the normal page https://ibb.co/k5gb30P

Comment: "Pre-fail" and "Old age" seem to signify a drive that's ready to kick the bucket.