# Trouble with size of partition (too small) after cloning disk/OS from USB flash drive to SSD

Tags: partitioning, ssd, dd, cloning

So, I have a Chromebook with two USB ports, a 128gb USB drive with my ideal Linux set up on it (Ubuntu 18.04, i3-gaps, other specific visual customizations) and an external/portable 500gb SSD that I would like to completely transfer said setup to. It's pretty clear to me that going into developer mode on my Chromebook and using `dd` in the command line is the best way to clone my setup. And after doing so successfully using:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=sdb bs=64 conv=sync,noerror status=progress
```

I ran into a problem. I realized that the partition was exactly copied of course, but this meant that it only recognized 128gb of space on the 500gb storage device, totally defeating the purpose of transferring the disk in the first place (i.e., having almost five times as much storage space).

My question, and I assume there must be a way, is how do I go about expanding/resizing the partition, either through the use of a flag in `dd` possibly, or after the partition has been cloned to the SSD perhaps? I'm at a loss and any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**
So, I've `dd`'d my drive over to the SSD for the second time after formatting it with the good ol' ext4 format. And it cloned it in the way I liked! No smaller partition keeping me from filling up the drive. But there's still a problem. Ubuntu, or more specifically Thunar and i3blocks (thus far) believe I only have 81.6GB of space left. What gives?

**UPDATE 2:**

This is what gparted is showing.

[image]

While gnome-disks says this,

[image]

and this when I try to use the resize feature. gparted says nothing in this regard as it wont let me select it's resize feature.

[image]

Any thoughts y'all?

Comment: Not that I am aware of if `dd` can resize the partition after copying.  I do know that [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/) is capable of cloning a smaller drive to a larger drive.  You might also want to see:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/574262/111521

Comment: Did you try gdisk, so you can move backup gpt partition table to end of drive. repair gpt:
http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html
More repair info  use p, v & w to write the partition table. If not correct just use q to quit. :
http://askubuntu.com/questions/386752/fixing-corrupt-backup-gpt-table/386802#386802
If gdisk does not work, the only other option is the SSD vendor's software. DD is really only for same size drive image copy.

Answer (score 1):

GNU Parted is a very useful tool for this kind of problem. If you are booting your image, and have a GUI, you can install it from the Ubuntu software store and it's very straightforward to use. Select the partition, right-click, select resize the partition. It will probably require a reboot to do the job.

Look for gparted in the software store.

If you can boot off the other USB drive and select the 500 GB drive in GParted, that might be helpful.