# Hard drive not showing a partition or any files after Windows install on another drive, it correctly shows only 34GB/TB available though

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I used to have two drives in my all Ubuntu computer, a 500GB NVME drive that I used for the OS and software and a second 2TB HDD that was to store larger files and backups. I added a third drive and installed Windows 10 on it a couple weeks ago and after that my 2TB HDD was no longer showing any files, although it did show only 34.7GB/2TB available, which seems correct. I was preoccupied with other things so I unplugged the 2TB HDD and went without until trying to fix it this past weekend.

I used ddrescue to backup the HDD partition to an external drive and ran "fsck -f /dev/sdc" (sdc is the drive) to try to repair it and that didn't help, if I look at the drive in GNOME Disks it shows the disk is healthy. I tried running testdisk and it detected the partition table as "None" and frankly I'm not sure where to go from here. My working assumption is that I screwed up the partition while installing Windows and I just don't know what's wrong or how to figure it out.

What should I do next?

Comment: Probably repartition and reformat the drive.

Comment: Are drives gpt or MBR(msdos). Windows in BIOS mode is known to erase partition table, deleting Linux partitions because it does not see them. Also if drive was default boot, Windows may have installed its ESP to beginning of drive, erasing whatever was there.  What does this show? `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sdc` And if not correct, does testdisk find old partitions?

Comment: @oldfred that command gives me

Caution! After loading partitions, the CRC doesn't check out!
Warning! Main partition table CRC mismatch! Loaded backup partition table
instead of main partition table!

Warning! One or more CRCs don't match. You should repair the disk!
Main header: OK
Backup header: OK
Main partition table: ERROR
Backup partition table: OK

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: damaged

Caution: Found protective or hybrid MBR and corrupt GPT. Using GPT, but disk
verification and recovery are STRONGLY recommended.

Comment: If you have good backups, then run the gdisk repairs. repair gpt:
http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html
More repair info  use p, v & w to write the partition table. If not correct just use q to quit. :
http://askubuntu.com/questions/386752/fixing-corrupt-backup-gpt-table/386802#386802