# Dual Boot Issue on Ubuntu 20.04 on Legion 7i

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I just recently tried to dual boot a new Legion 7i that I purchased: https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/p/laptops/legion-laptops/legion-7-series/legion-7i-gen-6-(16%E2%80%B3-intel)/82k6005sus?orgRef=https%253A%252F%252Faccount.lenovo.com%252F.

1. I basically shrank the pre-installed windows partition.
2. Created a EFI boot partition and a root partition because when I tried doing the installation with the "something else" option the Ubuntu installer complained it could not find an EFI partition. The "Install Ubuntu Alongside Windows" option never appeared in the installer.
3. Installed Ubuntu 20.04 on the newly created partition

It seems this broke my Windows partition because I could no longer see it in the BIOS and it didn't show on the grub loader even if I tried to do a grub repair. I tried to also recover the windows partition by creating an bootable windows disk but it can't even find the original partition anymore. I ended up doing a factory reset of the laptop using the Lenovo USB Recovery key and started over again. I searched around a bit I there were some suggestions so I did the following:

1. Turned off secure boot in the bios and turned off fastboot in Windows.
2. Created a free partition in windows: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCBuQ.jpg
3. Tried normal install again: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5x5o.jpg
4. Install alongside windows doesn't show again so I choose do "something else" because: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJwOh.jpg
5. These are the partitions provided to me again: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kAG2.jpg

At this point I'm sort of a loss on what to do so any advice would be much appreciated. Not sure if it has to do with the being nvme devices because I only have had experience in the past with sda devices. Thanks for reading!

*Edit* This is the output for `sudo parted -l`

Error: Invalid argument during seek for read on /dev/nvme0n1

Error: The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used.

Model: SAMSUNG MZVL21T0HCLR-00BL2 (nvme) Disk

/dev/nvme0n1: 1024GB

Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B

Partition Table: unknown Disk

Flags:

Error: /dev/nvme1n1: unrecognised disk label

Model: SAMSUNG MZVL21T0HCLR-00BL2 (nvme)

Disk /dev/nvme1n1: 1024GB

Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B

Partition Table: unknown

Disk Flags:

Comment: Please post partitions from terminal in question not as screen shot: `sudo parted -l` You need to update UEFI, update SSD firmware and use latest Ubuntu version as very new hardware. You also need "Safe Boot" for nVidia and install nVidia driver as part of install.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI
Shows Windows screens
https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi  Check if you also have a Security setting preventing install. You should only have one ESP per drive. Windows & Ubuntu will normally share that with different folders.

Comment: This is the output for `sudo parted -l`

Error: Invalid argument during seek for read on /dev/nvme0n1

Error: The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will
be used.

Model: SAMSUNG MZVL21T0HCLR-00BL2 (nvme)

Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 1024GB

Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B

Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags: 

Error: /dev/nvme1n1: unrecognised disk label
Model: SAMSUNG MZVL21T0HCLR-00BL2 (nvme)                                  
Disk /dev/nvme1n1: 1024GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags:

Comment: When using "somethin else" you, the user, are supposed to select the preexisting ESP along with at least / (root). That's all. You DON'T create another ESP in the same drive.

Comment: You really cannot post terminal output in comment, it loses format. Post in your question, so you can maintain the formatting. Install this: `sudo apt install nvme-cli` and run `sudo nvme -list` It will show model & FW revision. Then check if newer FirmWare is available: https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/download/tools/ I downloaded ISO and booted to update my Samsung NVMe drive. Repair gpt: http://askubuntu.com/questions/386752/fixing-corrupt-backup-gpt-table/386802#386802 But it looks like you erased drive.

Comment: Thanks. I think I figured out the issue was that the hard drive has been formatted to use RAID0 which seems to not work with the Ubuntu installer.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone runs into the same problem I did for installing Ubuntu on a Legion 7i, it's because the factory installation of Windows is on a RAID0. It seems that the Ubuntu installer has trouble finding the partitions or Windows when it is using RAID0. If you want to fix it I'd follow these instructions I found online for converting your Legion 7i to AHCI:
https://www.reddit.com/r/GamingLaptops/comments/oyvsud/psa_prebuild_legion_7i_owners_who_want_to_break/

Comment: Please [edit] and add the relevant details from the link to your answer

Answer (score 0):

I am running into a similar issue, after install I have a problem where the drives randomly unmount while in use.  I am going to try a re-install w/o dual booting and see if that fixes anything.

Other than the backlight everything else works very well on this machine its a beast.  Even sound is perfect for me.