# When Installing Ubuntu the partitions in my drive aren't recognised

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu to dual boot with Windows 10, which I already have installed on my laptop. I have reached the point where I can boot from an installation on an external USB drive, but have hit a roadblock in the installation process when I have to select an install location. I have partitioned my drive so that there's ~150GB of unused space that I plan to install Ubuntu into. When I go to pick a partition to install Ubuntu into it says that
[the entire drive is free space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEu5M.png).

While I could possibly just install here, I'm concerned that Ubuntu will overwrite my existing windows installation, as it doesn't seem to recognise my existing partitions. The drive has been partitioned using GPT, and when I use gdisk on the drive I get the [following errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jduhl.png).

Any advice on how I can repair my GPT table / install Ubuntu safely in my situation would be much appreciated.

ETA: The Ubuntu ISO I am using is the standard 22.04.2 ISO, for amd64

Comment: Providing clear details on your OS & release is always helpful; Ubuntu provides ISOs that currently use five different installers, but as you've not mention which Ubuntu product, we can only guess (also some product & releases have different ISOs available using different installers, but you've not told us if this applies to you, or which you elected to try?).  Please be specific & not make us guess.

Comment: @guiverc I am using a 22.04 LTS Ubuntu ISO, for amd64, sorry for not specifying.

Comment: Make sure UEFI & SSD firmware are latest versions. Check that Windows fast startup is off and bitlocker is off. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation  From gdisk run the fix suggested to repair header. http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html
More repair info  use p, v & w to write the partition table. If not correct just use q to quit. :
http://askubuntu.com/questions/386752/fixing-corrupt-backup-gpt-table/386802#386802

Comment: @oldfred thanks for your suggestions, will try them all and get back to you

Comment: Windows, with the "Fast Boot" option enabled, leaves disk partitions unrecognizable to Linux. Fix in Windows.

Comment: Your partition table/partitions seems to have severall significant problems. I suggest to delete everything and reinstall your OS. You also have to make sure to disable Windows Fastboot, otherwise you might corrupt data when using another OS on the same partitions.

Comment: You've narrowed down the product somewhat, giving release & architecture, but not said which product, ie. Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS Desktop? or Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS Server?  ie. the desktop uses `ubiquity` installer, server `subiquity` and *flavors* vary too (*but as you didn't mention a flavor you've probably ruled those out*)