# How do I change the partition format that was accidentally changed to MBR back to GPT?

Tags: boot, partitioning, uefi, data-recovery, gdisk

The first time my storage looked like this:

[image: First time my storage was look like this]

because I'm dual booting Ubuntu with Windows.

but accidentally my hard disk ends up like this:

[image: this]

After I checked with `gdisk` I got something like this:

[image: this]

HGST drive partitions:

[image: This is my HGST Drive Partitions]

How to fix this? I'm not sure how to run the 'w' option with that.

Comment: Most tools that convert drive, totally erase its partitions. It looks like gdisk found partition 4. What does it show with `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda`?  All your partitions? Do not post screen shot, but post output in question above.  It may be using backup gpt table which is one of gpt advantages. Do you have good backups?

Comment: What I mean is how do I change the hard disk back to GPT format so that the data can be accessed without changing or deleting the data on it?

Comment: My question still is  does gdisk show all the partitions? You have to include the -l in its command to see partitions. And use gpt not MBR. And do you have good backups. often conversion erases things. Do you know partitions starts by sector, from saved/back up of partition table info?

Comment: Your first image shows you selected the EVO drive and your second image shows you selected the HGST drive.  Which drive did you convert?  Your images are not showing that any drive was accidentally converted.

Comment: im sorry, that my bad. The HGST that I want to convert @Terrance and this image of all partitions in [HGST at GPT format](https://imgur.com/a/5Zxxkpf)

Comment: The HGST Hard Drive should have a partition format sequence that is similar to the partition format sequence that the Samsung Evo has, but the HGST Hard Drive instead has the MBR and GPT format types, which were originally GPT format types. That's why I included the first image in this post. I also haven't backed up the data on the HGST Drive because this just happened @oldfred

Comment: All gpt drives have a protective MBR. That just has one entry saying entire drive is gpt. And that is to prevent older formatting tools that are MBR only from damaging drive structure.

Comment: How to make it as it should be? @oldfred and the result of partition table scan shouldn't look like [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5SyP.png) if I run ```sudo gdisk /dev/sdb``` command but like ```
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present
```

Comment: To see entire gpt partition table you must include the -l `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sdb`.  See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/386752/fixing-corrupt-backup-gpt-table/386802#386802