Ubuntu existing installation / new setup - No disks found
I'm having issues installing or using existing installation on my new homelab setup.
I've looked many articles and questions on here and documentation about Intel RST but was unable to identify a solution:

Computer does recognize the disks, as I can see them in the BIOS settings, see #4 above as well
There are 3xSSD (256gb, 2x1tb) connected to the motherboard SATA, and 1 NVMe (2TB) connected to the motherboard M.2, and 1 HDD (1TB) connected through a PCIe 1x to 2 SATA ports. I tried unplugging the PCIe card, made no difference
I tried USB server install (balenaEtcher) for jammy and noble, with normal and HWE - kernel logs from install are available here: https://pastebin.com/aksFnFRv
Disks located by Ubuntu are the 1 HDD PCiE and NVMe (used lsblk). Mint / Kali / OpenMediaVault and Proxmox Live / Install have all disks listed
The MB is a Biostar H610HMP ver 6.1 with latest BIOS. I tried multiple BIOS configs: enabling / Disabling VMD controller, turning on Legacy mode vs UEFI (CSM Support in BIOS), enabled / disabled FastBoot, enabled / disabled SATA Self Test. BIOS does not have an AHCI / Legacy Mode option, just SATA Enabled / Disabled - the latter didn't work as well.
One of the SSDs has an Ubuntu installation on it - tried running it, but it fails after the raid6 kernel messages and a couple of mdadm messages. That SSD has a default server install (fat32 /boot/efi + ext4 / partitions)
I tried boot repair from Linux mint, that did a couple of chroot grub changes, but didn't work. BootInfo logs can be found here: https://sprunge.us/iMh2Ec
I did not try netinstall, as I figured it would be give me the same results as USB - but can serve the ISO from my other SBC server.
I have no other OS running on this computer, neither I want to run another OS natively.

Given the above, I really need some guidance on some next steps - troubleshooting or otherwise.
I want to have my server running Ubuntu, but that is simply not being possible right now.
UPDATE: issue only happens for Jammy and Noble. Focal and Bionic are working just fine. Kernel related?

Do not turn on legacy mode & keep VMD driver. Have you checked motherboard manual. NVMe drives almost always conflict with a SATA port, then one drive or the other will not work. Do not know about zfs errors. And modprobe is looking in wrong place. /lib/modules/5.15.0-91-generic. My modeprobe gives same error as they are in /sys/firmware/efi/efivars, not sure if grub or Boot-Repair issue.

@oldfred I tried both VMD enabled and disabled. both didn`t make a change. the NVMe conflicts with sata port 4, and the boot drive is on sata port 1. also, it cannot find any disks, regardless of port. It was not locating disks even before I plugged in the NVMe.

Before finding on my system that the VMD driver worked without changing to AHCI mode, we always suggested changing from RAID to AHCI. If dual booting with Windows you have to install AHCI drivers. My VMD is only for one NVMe drive, so no other drives are involved. Have you tried AHCI mode for drives in UEFI settings? Do you have latest firmware for motherboard & all drives? sudo lshw | grep -m 1 -A 5 "*-firmware" &
udisksctl status
Compare to vendors support page.

@oldfred not dual booting. VMD is disabled, and there is no option to change RAID to AHCI. I assume disabling VMD gives ahci, because that is how other distros boot - in AHCI mode. I do have latest firmware, and the computer works just fine with other distros.

I do not know server installs. I use Kubuntu on desktop & laptop. But see this: "GPT:Alternate GPT header not at the end of the disk." See this for each gpt drive: https://askubuntu.com/questions/386752/fixing-corrupt-backup-gpt-table/386802#386802
