ext4 partition that was recovered After Windows installed their bootloader on it keeps on getting repartitioned
First, here is how my disks are setup physically for future reference:
SATA 1: 480 GB SSD (ext4, Running Ubuntu Server 20.04.1 LTS) (\dev\sda)
SATA 2: 4 TB HDD (ext4, Data) (\dev\sdb)
SATA 3: 512 GB SSD

This whole ordeal started when I attempted to install Windows Server 2016 on the 512 GB SSD on SATA 3. I believe that it installed somewhat correctly on the 512 GB SSD, but for whatever reason it installed the Windows bootloader on my 4TB HDD data drive which was initially formatted with ext4, wiping out the partition.
After running testdisk it found the partition and gave me the command to fix it using fsck: sudo fsck.ext4 -p -v -b 98304 -B 4096 /dev/sdb and it restored it correctly back to ext4 and I am able to mount it and see all my files both in the terminal and through samba. Here are the logs from fsck:
/dev/sdb was not cleanly unmounted, check forced.
/dev/sdb: Padding at end of inode bitmap is not set. FIXED.
/dev/sdb: Group 1 block bitmap does not match checksum.
FIXED.

      292318 inodes used (0.12%, out of 244195328)
         655 non-contiguous files (0.2%)
          17 non-contiguous directories (0.0%)
             # of inodes with ind/dind/tind blocks: 0/0/0
             Extent depth histogram: 292009/301
   263963353 blocks used (27.02%, out of 976754646)
           0 bad blocks
         108 large files

      266548 regular files
       25761 directories
           0 character device files
           0 block device files
           0 fifos
           0 links
           0 symbolic links (0 fast symbolic links)
           0 sockets
------------
      292309 files

Here is the output of sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,UUID that shows /dev/sdb with the ext4 filesystem:
NAME               FSTYPE        SIZE MOUNTPOINT         UUID
sda                            447.1G
├─sda1             vfat          512M /boot/efi          5A01-7DC4
├─sda2                             1K
└─sda5             LVM2_member 446.6G                    R3zMkp-ZCBC-zNlH-TFtg-uXee-0BOJ-jQJia0
  ├─vgbserv-root   ext4        445.7G /                  195abfb9-5865-483e-91fc-1143ce9cd8ff
  └─vgbserv-swap_1 swap          980M [SWAP]             c5f11ac5-4240-4863-b40c-86c31ef17880
sdb                ext4          3.7T /home/bolsen/samba 7517dc94-5dea-4af5-ae48-62a087e25c48

The problem comes whenever I reboot, for whatever reason it repartitions the drive such that sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,UUID displays the following:
NAME               FSTYPE        SIZE MOUNTPOINT UUID
sda                            447.1G
├─sda1             vfat          512M /boot/efi  5A01-7DC4
├─sda2                             1K
└─sda5             LVM2_member 446.6G            R3zMkp-ZCBC-zNlH-TFtg-uXee-0BOJ-jQJia0
  ├─vgbserv-root   ext4        445.7G /          195abfb9-5865-483e-91fc-1143ce9cd8ff
  └─vgbserv-swap_1 swap          980M [SWAP]     c5f11ac5-4240-4863-b40c-86c31ef17880
sdb                              3.7T
├─sdb1                           450M
└─sdb2             vfat           99M            125D-251E

And once again to recover it I have to run fsck every time it reboots. Before this all happened I automatically mounted /dev/sdb on startup for samba to use, this is what /etc/fstab looked like before I commented out the line that mounted it on startup:
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/vgbserv-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=5A01-7DC4  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/dev/mapper/vgbserv-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=7517dc94-5dea-4af5-ae48-62a087e25c48 /home/bolsen/samba ext4

I first noticed this problem when I restarted my server and it could not mount it.
Here are the things I have tried to fix it (all of these I tried after restoring /dev/sdb):

Ran sudo mount /dev/sdb /mnt & sudo umount /dev/sdb /mnt and rebooted.
Shutdown & disconnected the 512 SSD on SATA 3 and started the server.
Commented out the entry for the drive in /etc/fstab

Still no luck, whenever I reboot the server /dev/sdb is still repartitioned.
Here is some system information in case that helps:
lsb_release -a:
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal

lshw -class disk (This is it when the ext4 partition is intact after fsck & mount as well as the 512 GB SSD disconnected):
  *-disk
       description: ATA Disk
       product: CT480BX500SSD1
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sda
       version: 054
       serial: 2222E6366075
       size: 447GiB (480GB)
       capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
       configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512 signature=2e68eb1b
  *-disk
       description: ATA Disk
       product: ST4000DM004-2CV1
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sdb
       logical name: /home/bolsen/samba
       version: 0001
       serial: ZTT4K3K6
       size: 3726GiB (4TB)
       capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
       configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=48da1333-c886-481d-80ba-cdbe0d23b975 logicalsectorsize=512 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime sectorsize=4096 state=mounted

fdisk -l (Again, this is after fsck & mount was run with the 512 GB SSD missing):
Disk /dev/sda: 447.13 GiB, 480103981056 bytes, 937703088 sectors
Disk model: CT480BX500SSD1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x2e68eb1b

Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048   1050623   1048576   512M  b W95 FAT32
/dev/sda2       1052670 937701375 936648706 446.6G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1052672 937701375 936648704 446.6G 8e Linux LVM


The primary GPT table is corrupt, but the backup appears OK, so that will be used.
Disk /dev/sdb: 3.65 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Disk model: ST4000DM004-2CV1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 48DA1333-C886-481D-80BA-CDBE0D23B975

Device      Start     End Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1    2048  923647  921600  450M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sdb2  923648 1126399  202752   99M EFI System


Disk /dev/mapper/vgbserv-root: 445.68 GiB, 478532337664 bytes, 934633472 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/vgbserv-swap_1: 980 MiB, 1027604480 bytes, 2007040 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Is there something I am misunderstanding? Is there a way I can repair the partition without having to back everything up first?
Thanks,

"The primary GPT table is corrupt. " Have you repaired sdb? And you say you ran fsck on sdb, but you only run it on partitions like sdb`. So did you format drive, not partition(s)? http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html & http://askubuntu.com/questions/386752/fixing-corrupt-backup-gpt-table/386802#386802

Unallocate and then remove from /etc/stab the 99mb partition and just forget about ever using it. I'm pretty sure this will solve the fsck issue. You could also modify the script so it doesn't start, or use some monitoring software which probes for whatever condition and deals with it. Just unallocate and remove from fstab that little partition.

@oldfred So I repaired the GPT table using the backup with gdisk sudo gdisk /dev/sdb, this brought it back to the two partitions that I see whenever I restart the machine. Neither of these partitions have any of my data on them. For whatever reason whenever I rerun fsck.ext4 on /dev/sdb it corrupts the GPT table again but all my data is there just fine with no partitions. Finally, when I use testdisk with those two partitions on the disk it only shows the ext4 partition with all of my data.

Typo in my comment, you only run fsck on partitions like sda1, missed 1. You cannot run fsck on sda. If testdisk shows partitions correctly in gpt mode then use it to restore partition. Or was drive really MBR and gpt data is wrong? Windows is known to convert gpt drives to MBR, leaving backup gpt table. Then you have issues. Best to always have gpt, unless using Windows in old BIOS boot mode which requires MBR on boot drive only.
