Unable to boot Ubuntu 22.04 on acer Aspire Lite AL15G 52
I’m currently using Ubuntu 24.04 on Acer Aspire Lite AL15G 52 and trying to downgrade to Ubuntu 22.04 by booting from a USB drive. However, the system freezes during the boot process from the USB. Below is a picture of error am encountering

I created the iso image using "dd" with command: sudo dd if=ubuntu.iso of=/dev/sda status=progress bs=10M && sync but i don't think that's the issue here cause i installed Ubuntu 24.04 in the exact same way and boot settings and chose the option to erase disk (uninstall windows 11) and it worked.
Edit 1: I am trying to install ubuntu-22.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso and previously i installed ubuntu-24.04-desktop-amd64.iso without any issues with same boot settings.
Edit 2: Based on @oldfred's comment, here's the output of "gdisk" command:
$ sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.10

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
Disk /dev/sda: 244457472 sectors, 116.6 GiB
Model: SanDisk 3.2 Gen1
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): ABBD44C4-640C-4CEA-ACCB-CA38273F602E
Partition table holds up to 248 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 63
First usable sector is 64, last usable sector is 9799460
Partitions will be aligned on 4-sector boundaries
Total free space is 1 sectors (512 bytes)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1              64         9788791   4.7 GiB     0700  ISO9660
   2         9788792         9798859   4.9 MiB     EF00  Appended2
   3         9798860         9799459   300.0 KiB   0700  Gap1

Apart from "dd", i also used "etcher" to flash the ISO again and even reflashed the ISO with "dd" again but cleared the partition table with: sudo wipefs --all /dev/sda this time to see if it works & encountered the same error in both cases. I even changed my USB to another one but that also resulted in same error so i assume it has nothing to do with the USB am using.

You're somewhat vague on details... No product for a start only providing release details. Ubuntu 22.04 ISOs exist that use the 5.15, 5.19. 6.2, 6.5 & 6.8 kernels, but you've not said which you attempted as your 24.04 will have used a 6.8 kernel so did you try that kernel with 22.04? or an older one?  WHich did you try?  A Server ISO? and which, or Desktop ISO? and which?

@guiverc I used the Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop ISO from the official Ubuntu website -> https://releases.ubuntu.com/jammy/ and I’m using UEFI mode for booting. Unfortunately my pc doesn't allow switching to legacy either and my secure boot is off. Previously i booted Ubuntu 24.04 desktop ISO as well. link -> https://releases.ubuntu.com/noble/

Ubuntu has released 5 versions of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop; the initial & .1 media used 5.15, 22.04.2 used 5.19, 22.04.3 used 6.2, 22.04.4 used 6.5 & the 22.04.5 or current daily uses 6.8 ... the link you provided has varied what it offers based on when accessed; so it's best if you're specific with details; such as  ubuntu-22.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso was what you downloaded (ie. 22.04.4 Desktop)

Thanks for clearing that out and your help, I downloaded ubuntu-22.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso and previously i installed ubuntu-24.04-desktop-amd64.iso without any issues. Actually i just purchased this pc the day before yesterday so i downloaded the latest ones as shown in the link.

You show alternative gpt header not at end of drive. What does sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda show? http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html  & https://askubuntu.com/questions/386752/fixing-corrupt-backup-gpt-table/386802#386802

@oldfred Does that mean the issue could be with the device am trying to boot the iso with? I've added the output from "gdisk" command in my question, Please check it out.

Is flash drive sda or install drive sda? And often boot of a flash drive promotes flash drive to first drive. If flash drive was gpt and you used dd or one of the install tools to write ISO to flash drive, it would leave a backup gpt table. And then should not be a problem until you want to use it again. And have to erase partition table with dd to make drive usable again.  When using dd, it creates a hybrid DVD/flash drive installer.

@oldfred /dev/sda is the flash or USB drive. in BIOS, Boot Order settings am quite sure am booting to USB (/dev/sda) manually. Apart from dd i also used "etcher" to flash the ISO again and tried to reflash the ISO with "dd" again but cleard the partition table with: sudo wipefs --all /dev/sda this time & i still encountered the same error in both cases.
